# Class with a nested collection - how do I populate the nested class?

Tags: autofixture

I'm a bit confused as to hydrate a class with a nested collection of another class.
I get the error:

> AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[typename...]

I've tried to use `Fixture.Register()` to register the type for populating the inner class.
I could just to do with a sample which shows

1. The main class
2. The nested collection (IList/IEnumerable) of another class.

I've also noticed that `Register()` is marked as obsolete, yet there is no documentation on the `Inject()` method on CodePlex so I'm stumped as to how this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoFixture makes no presumptions on how to instantiate instances of interfaces, but you can [pretty easily enable the behavior you seek](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/07/CreatingSpecificPopulatedListsWithAutoFixture.aspx) - e.g. for integers:

```
fixture.Register(() => fixture.CreateMany<int>());
```

In the upcoming AutoFixture 2.1 you can also just [enable conventions for various collections](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/08/CreatingGeneralPopulatedListsWithAutoFixture.aspx) with a single method call:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new MultipleCustomization());
```

Regarding the deprecation of the Register method, please notice that it's only a single overload of the Register method that's marked obsolete. The Inject method is the direct replacement - it has the same signature and usage, just a different name. All the other Register overloads are not deprecated and should be used as 'documented'.