# How to create an IList of anonymous classes using AutoFixture

Tags: c#, autofixture

I previously posted a question on this link:

[Class with a nested collection - how do I populate the nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458137/class-with-a-nested-collection-how-do-i-populate-the-nested-class)

I need to be able to do the same but with nested classes:

like so:

```
public class ParentClass
{
   public int Value;
   public IList<ChildClass> Children;
}

public class ChildClass
{
   etc...
}
```

I tried this:

```
Fixture.Register(()=>Fixture.CreateMany<ChildClass>();
```

But this isn't working, any ideas?
I'm using AutoFixture 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AutoProperties features of AutoFixture only assigns values to writable properties. The reason why `ParentClass.Children` isn't being populated is because it's a read-only property - AutoFixture doesn't attempt to assign a value because it knows that this is impossible.

However, assuming that you already have an instance of ParentClass, you can ask AutoFixture to fill the collection for you:

```
fixture.AddManyto(parentClass.Children);
```

This can be encapsulated into a customization like this:

```
fixture.Customize<ParentClass>(c => c.Do(pc => fixture.AddManyTo(pc.Children)));
```

Since `Children` is an `IList<ChildClass>` you'll also need to provide a mapping for that unless you use the [MultipleCustomization](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/02/08/CreatingGeneralPopulatedListsWithAutoFixture.aspx):

```
fixture.Register<IList<ChildClass>>(() => fixture.CreateMany<ChildClass>().ToList());
```

This is definitely a behavior that we [considered adding to the MultipleCustomization, but decided to postpone until after release 2.1](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4199) because it turns out to be not entirely easy to implement.

Comment: Great thanks! I managed to get that working although the customize didn't work for me. I used just the register method.

Comment: OK, good - I have to admit that I wrote the above code directly into my answer, so there may be a slight error somewhere... but the general idea is correct :)